# Raising Indices of a Conformally Transformed Metric

Tags: differential-geometry

This is a bit of a silly question, but if a conformally transformed metric is given by

$g_{ij} = A^4 h_{ij}$,

where $A$ is a function of the spatial and time coordinates, and if one raises the indices does one accordingly have

$g^{ij} = A^4 h^{ij}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g^{ij}$ is typically defined as the pointwise inverse of the metric, $g^{ij}g_{jk}=\delta^i_k$. As such, if you have a conformally related metric $g_{ij}=A^4h_{ij}$, the inverse  would have the reciprocal of the conformal factor $g^{ij}=A^{-4}h^{ij}$.